# Is there a way to enter automate entering credentials in the IWA and SAML popup using only python and selenium

Tags: selenium, python

[image]I am trying to create an automation script for a website that supports both IWA and SAML authentication. In case of IWA, whenever I hit the URL using the selenium driver, I get a Authentication Required popup. I need to automate this step to login with different credentials and check the website.

I have tried using `HttpNtlmAuth` but I always get Response 401. Is there a way to achieve this by using only python and selenium?

Comment: Could you show a screenshot of this authentication popup? Is this the basic HTTP auth popup?

Comment: Hi, its not a basic HTTP Popup. I will add a screenshot to the question.

Comment: Thanks, have you tried approaching it by simply navigating to `https://username:password@yourdomain.com`?

Comment: Hi, I did try to approach it by appending the username and password in the URL but it is not working. Thanks